# videowhisper live streaming php script with red 5 or wowza

Tags: php, localhost, red5, live-streaming, wowza

so i tryed to setup my own rtmp server with red5 and i want to use my own local red5 rtmp address for my streaming website (like ustream with videowhisper). So my users can stream and watch streams from others over my server on my website and i dont have to buy expencive servers online. Videowhisper needs a rtmp adress. so please can someone tell me how to do this and what im needing for this.

I installed red5 on my localhost and the server is started and running. In Videowhisper i set the rtmp to rtmp://myipaddress but i get a connection failed.

here is settings.php

```
<?php

$rtmp_server = "rtmp://localhost:1935/videowhisper-live";
// rtmp://your-server-ip-or-domain/application

$rtmp_amf = "AMF3";
// AMF3 : Red5, Wowza, FMIS3, FMIS3.5
// AMF0 : FCS1.5, FMS2
// blank for flash default

$rtmfp_server="rtmfp://stratus.adobe.com/f1533cc06e4de4b56399b10d-          1a624022ff71/";
// RTMFP server for negotiangin P2P connections where possible
// Get your own independent developer key/address from:        https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=stratus

$tokenKey = "VideoWhisper";
// This can be used to secure access as configured in RTMP server settings     (secureTokenSharedSecret).

$ban_names=Array("ban_name1", "ban_name2");
//ban channel or user names

$httpstreamer="http://localhost:1935/videowhisper/";
//path for HTTP Live Stre streaming usually available with Wowza hosting if packetizers are enabled
//use http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=Wowza+Media+Server+Hosting or see    http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217#cupertinostreaming


//usage limit per channel
//default 2 hours per week limit
$maximumSessionTime=7200000; //7200000 ms = 2h; 0 for unlimited
$resetTime = 7 * 3600 * 24; //weekly

?>
```

if someone know how to do this with wowza that ok i have installed wowza also

please can someone help me im searching for a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you set the RTMP address correctly, including the port and stream name, and you can play this stream in your local network then there's a good chance that something is blocking communication on port 1935 between your Red5 server and Videowhisper.

Since 1935 can be blocked by firewalls you can try to configure your streaming server to use a well known port such as 80 or 8080 instead.